# how handling retrive data json array nested in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http-post

I want to retrive data json array nested to UI interface in flutter.
I have my model and ui, but i don't understand, please advice and corrected my code to implement in ui.

this my model

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

MutasiRekResponse myModelFromJson(String str) => MutasiRekResponse.fromJson(json.decode(str));
String myModelToJson(MutasiRekResponse data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class MutasiRekResponse {
    String responseCode;
    String responseMessage;
    String date;
    String time;
    String accNumber;
    String startDate;
    String endDate;
    List<Content> content;

    MutasiRekResponse({
        this.responseCode,
        this.responseMessage,
        this.date,
        this.time,
        this.accNumber,
        this.startDate,
        this.endDate,
        this.content,
    });

    factory MutasiRekResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MutasiRekResponse(
        responseCode: json["responseCode"],
        responseMessage: json["responseMessage"],
        date: json["date"],
        time: json["time"],
        accNumber: json['accNumber'],
        content: List<Content>.from(json["content"].map((x) => Content.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "responseCode": responseCode,
        "responseMessage": responseMessage,
        "date": date,
        "time": time,
        "accNumber": accNumber,
        "content": List<dynamic>.from(content.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Content {
    String postingDate;
    String valueDate;
    String inputDate;
    String inputTime;
    String desc;
    String noReff;
    String amount;
    String balance;

    Content({
        this.postingDate,
        this.valueDate,
        this.inputDate,
        this.inputTime,
        this.desc,
        this.noReff,
        this.amount,
        this.balance,
    });

    factory Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Content(
        postingDate: json["postingDate"],
        valueDate: json["valueDate"],
        inputDate: json["inputDate"],
        inputTime: json["inputTime"],
        desc: json["desc"],
        noReff: json["noReff"],
        amount: json["amount"],
        balance: json["balance"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "postingDate": postingDate,
        "valueDate": valueDate,
        "inputDate": inputDate,
        "inputTime": inputTime,
        "desc": desc,
        "noReff": noReff,
        "amount": amount,
        "balance": balance,
    };

  static Future<MutasiRekResponse> getMutasiDetails(String accNumber, String startDate, String endDate) async {
  String apiURL ="urlAPI";
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";

    var bytes = utf8.encode("$username:$password");
    var credentials = base64.encode(bytes);
    var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Basic $credentials"
    };

  var params = Map<String, dynamic>();
  params['accNumber'] = accNumber;
  params['startDate'] = startDate;
  params['endDate'] = endDate;

  http.Response apiResult =
      await http.post(apiURL, body: params, headers: headers);
  if (apiResult.statusCode == 200) {
    return MutasiRekResponse.fromJson(json.decode(apiResult.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('failed to load data');
  }
}
}
```

this UI interface

```
import 'package:myfolder/models/riwayatTrx_mdl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RiwayatTransaksi extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RiwayatTransaksiState createState() => RiwayatTransaksiState();
}

class RiwayatTransaksiState extends State<RiwayatTransaksi> {
  RiwayatTrxResult riwayatTrxResult;
@override
  void initState() {
    RiwayatTrxResult.connectToAPI("0002100000291", "", "").then((value) {
      riwayatTrxResult = value;
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SafeArea(
        child: new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF4F4F4),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Riwayat'),
        ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                'Riwayat Transaksi',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            _historyWidget(riwayatTrxResult),
          ],
        ),
      ),
     ),
   );
  }

  //HOW I DO CALL METHOD FOR LOOP
  Widget _historyWidget(RiwayatTrxResult riwayatTrxResult) {
    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0, left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
    );
  }  
}
```

API JSON Response

```
{
  "responseCode": "0000",
  "responseMessage": "Success",
  "date": "20200302",
  "time": "170248",
  "branchCode": "0000",
  "branchName": "BRANCH ONE",
  "accNumber": "0002100000291",
  "name": "MYNAME",
  "address": "jl wr supratman",
  "city": "Kab Kota Lainnya Bali",
  "postalCode": "10110",
  "totalTrx": "5",
  "content": [
    {
      "postingDate": "20191203",
      "valueDate": "20191203",
      "inputDate": "20191203",
      "inputTime": "214808",
      "desc": "BUNGA DEPOSITO JATUH TEMPO",
      "noReff": "B2100000000026",
      "amount": "+20712,33",
      "balance": "+6971357445,15"
    },
    {
      "postingDate": "20191203",
      "valueDate": "20191203",
      "inputDate": "20191203",
      "inputTime": "214809",
      "desc": "BUNGA DEPOSITO JATUH TEMPO",
      "noReff": "B2100000000033",
      "amount": "+13808,22",
      "balance": "+6971371253,37"
    },
  ]
}
```

how to call method and handling retrive data in ui, but i don't understand, please advice and corrected my code to implement in ui.

Comment: Did you create this code yourself, but don't understand it?

Comment: ya, i learn from internet. i new programmer, i confused the looping. model i using convert json to dart tools online.

Comment: It's already to still be learning, we all started the same way. You might want to try to understand how the basics work before using code generators. It will make it easier to learn gradually.

Comment: please example your code called model in ui. thanks

Comment: please post your full json response string and ping my name, thanks.

Comment: @chunhungan, I was added json in above. thanks.